# how to execute monkeyrunner commands in shell (terminal)

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, monkeyrunner

When I start my scrip from the shell I do something like this

```
monkeyrunner myScriptFile
```

and then

in myScriptFile I have content like this

```
    from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    device.installPackage('myproject/bin/MyApplication.apk')
.....
```

and everything works fine, but I want to do something more fancy :), I want to write everything from the terminal(shell)

so is it possible to write everything in shell ? I mean is it possible the commands that are written in myScriptFile to be executed directly in shell without additional file like myScriptFile

or with other words is it possible to execute the 'from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice' command in shell ?

Answer (score 0):

1. To install package you can use `adb` instead of `monkeyrunner`:

   `adb install -r 'myproject/bin/MyApplication.apk'`
2. if you write shell script, you can use shell here string syntax to avoid separate file with monkeyrunner script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

./monkeyrunner <<EOL
# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

# Takes a screenshot
result = device.takeSnapshot()

# Writes the screenshot to a file
result.writeToFile('1.png','png')
EOL
```